# How to make the background color not to stick to the background Image when dragging?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, drag, chess

I am making a chess game on React, and tried to add a drag and drop functionality to the chess pieces, the problem is that the background color style applied to the parent div sticking to the child div which is a draggable element with background image of the chess piece, here is the code of component:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {Cell} from "../models/Cell";

interface CellProps {
    cell: Cell;
    selected: boolean;
    click: (cell: Cell) => void;
    handleDrag: (e: React.DragEvent, celltype: Cell) => void;
    handleDragOver: (e: React.DragEvent) => void;
    handleOnDrop: (e: React.DragEvent, cell:Cell) => void;

}


const CellComponent: FC<CellProps> = ({cell, selected, click, handleDrag, handleDragOver, handleOnDrop}) => {

    return (
        <div
            className={['cell', cell.color, selected && cell.figure ? "selected" : '', ].join(' ')}
            onClick={() => click(cell)}
            onDrop={(e) => handleOnDrop(e, cell)}
            onDragOver={handleDragOver}
        >
            {cell.available && cell.figure && <div className={"figure-available"}/>}
            {cell.available && !cell.figure && <div className={"available"}/>}

            <div
                onDragStart={(e) => handleDrag(e, cell)}
                draggable
            >
                {cell.figure?.logo &&  <div style={{
                    backgroundImage: cell.figure.logo ? `url(${cell.figure.logo})` : 'none',
                    width: '80px',
                    height:'80px',
                    backgroundRepeat:'no-repeat',
                    backgroundPosition: 'center',
                    backgroundSize:'80px'

                }} />}

            </div>



        </div>

)
};

export default CellComponent;
```

And the css code applied to the parent div:

```
.cell {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.black {
background-color: #b58863;
}

.white {
background-color: #f0d9b5;
}

.selected {
background-color: teal;
background-color: rgba(40, 146, 146, 0.7);

}

.available {
height: 23px;
width: 23px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: rgba(40, 146, 146, 0.7);
}

.figure-available {
height: 80px;
width:80px;
position: absolute;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 77%, rgba(60, 146, 146, 0.7) 77%);

}
```

Replacing the div by img tag indeed drags only the image without the background color, but the browser thinks that I am trying to open a media file, which is not what I want. I want the browser to treat the dragged element as an element and drag only the image whithout any background color applied.